# DataRow comparison not working as expected

Tags: c#, datarow

I'm trying to compare two `DataRow`s in a loop. However, the following `if` statement doesn't return `true`:

```
if (dt1.Rows[0]["Name"] == dt2.Rows[b]["Name"]) {
    // This never executes
}
```

However, if I add `.ToString()` to the end of each `DataRow`, the `if` statement returns `true`:

```
if (dt1.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString() == dt2.Rows[b]["Name"].ToString()) {
    // This now executes
}
```

The column "Name" is from the same table/column. So the question is quite simple... What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Stephen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [itsmatt has said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614713/datarow-comparison-not-working-as-expected/614725#614725), your first snippet is doing a reference comparison. An alternative to calling `ToString` is to use `Object.Equals`:

```
if (Object.Equals(dt1.Rows[0]["Name"], dt2.Rows[b]["Name"])) {
    // stuff
}
```

The reason for using the static method instead of the instance method is to avoid problems with null references.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and code sample. I didn't really want to use .ToString(), it didn't feel right somehow :)

Answer (score 9):

Those cells hold objects so you are doing an object comparison, which just does a reference comparison, which is different from a value comparison.  It asks the question "Are these two objects really the same object?", essentially are they referring to the same object, hence "reference comparison".  When you do the ToString() call, you are then doing string comparison.  That is why it works.

[Here's a link to MS's discussion of Operator== and comparison.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Is there any work around or is .ToString() the best I can do?

Answer (score 4):

The `==` operator, if not overloaded, is identical to `ReferenceEquals()` -- that is, it determines whether two given `object`s are the same instances.

The call to `ToString()` returns an object of `string` class, which has overloaded `==` operator, which does string comparison.

Comment: Important: it's not an *overridden* == operator, it's an *overloaded* operator.